# Querying many-to-many relations via associative table with Prisma

Tags: prisma

I'm new to Prisma and while it's been incredibly easy to pick up so far, I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to find a good answer to. I've read through the [docs about relation queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries), but from my understanding Prisma doesn't have any support for many-to-many via fluent api. Every query must return a single entity and then you can add the related table, but in my case my query will return many entities that I then would like to join on.

Here's a quick example of my schema:

```
model User {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
}


model Workspace {
  id String  @id @default(uuid())
}

model WorkspaceUser {
  workspace   Workspace @relation(fields: [workspaceId], references: [id])
  workspaceId String
  user        User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId      String
}
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
await prisma.workspaceUser.findMany({
  where: { userId: "123" },
}).workspaces();
```

Also, I noticed that intellisense shows there is a .join() method, but it's not mentioned in the docs.

Does Prisma offer a solution to this problem, or should I use `$queryRaw`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use that exact syntax for single selects aka

```
await prisma.workspaceUser.findUnique({
  where: { userId: "123" },
}).workspace();
```

For many selections it will be returned as an array but should still have the related entity if you specify `include`

```
const allRecords = await prisma.workspaceUser.findMany({
  where: { userId: "123" },
  include: {workspace: true},
});
```

Then you can do something like `allRecords[i].workspace;`

Comment: This took me an unnecessary amount of time to realize. Thank you ! Additionally, is there a way to continue populating the relations of the tables you include? In your code above, lets say workspace has a relation to another table too

Comment: yes you keep nesting the `include` statements or `select` statements

Comment: @AdamJames there is a easy way to resollve this case? I want the response will be this => Response: User {
......., workspaces: Workspace[] (only filter by id from woorkspaceuser tablle)
}